# Parsing JSON with jQuery Mustache template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I am complete rookie to Javascript, jQuery and JSON. For the most part the JSON data is displaying correctly. I have a list of JSON array comments that is rendered in HTML. I would like to include a different background color for list items. I realize that Mustache is a logicless template but can this be achieved. Below are the codes. Any advise will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
        <div id="contentbox">
    <div id="commentslist"></div>
</div>

<script id="commentstpl" type="text/template">
    <ul class="comment-content">
        {{#comments}}
            <li class="rightcol-list-content odd">
            {{comment}}<br>
            <strong>{{name}}</strong>, {{timestamp}}
            </li>
        {{/comments}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $.getJSON('app.json', function(data) {
            var template = $('#commentstpl').html();
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $('#commentslist').html(html);
        }); //getJSON

    }); //function

</script>
```

JSON data:

```
        {
    "comments": [
    {
     "name": "John Smith",
     "comment": "Would like background in light gray",
     "timestamp": "18-11-2013"
     },
     {
     "name": "Jane Doe",
     "comment": "Would like background to be dark gray",
     "timestamp": "26-11-1991"
     },
     {
     "name": "Amy Lang",
     "comment": "Would like background in light gray",
     "timestamp": "30-5-1991"
     },
    {
     "name": "Jessica Rabbit",
     "comment": "Would like background to be dark gray",
     "timestamp": "23-5-1988"
     }
     ]
}
```

Comment: First determine what rule you want to use to determine the background colour. Is it based on something in the data or is it just alternating?

Comment: I would like to use CSS to determine the background color. Perhaps create a new field in the JSON data "isOdd": "true" and parse with jQuery calling out the data object isOdd and render using CSS like so     // Change background colour of alternating posts                
            $("data.json.IsOdd").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)").trigger("create");Would this work? If so do I place this within the same getJSON function or can it be added to the external app.json file?

Comment: You missed the point of my question. I'm asking what logic should determine the colour, not what technology you want to implement that logic in. It sounds like what you are really trying to achieve is "Make every other row a different colour" and that modifying the data file is a means to the end.